# Writing Batch Script to Install Software and Dependencies

Tags: batch-file, deployment, automation, installation

I'm currently working with a .NET 4.5 application whose installation I am looking to automate more. It has approximately 4-5 dependencies, such as drivers and sdk's that I've collected. Currently, I manually run through each installer and it is rather inefficient. I would like to write a script to run the installers for me, but have done nothing of this nature and don't know where to start.

I've searched for examples but many of the resources that seem relevant no longer have available links. Any guidance on scripting of this nature, or installation automation is more than welcome!

Comment: You should usually be able to just call the installers from the batch file. i.e. `call installer.exe` with whatever switches it might take.

Comment: I figured it can't be terribly difficult, but I'm sad to say the command line is not something I use often. I've found the windows command line reference so I will attempt to stumble through it using that.

Comment: @unclemeat So when you say switches, do you mean I can give it the answer to dialog boxes that would come up if I ran it via the GUI? How do I specify them?

Comment: Switches are parameters that you pass to a script or executable - for example some switches for the `dir` command are `/s` and `/b`.

Comment: I can't tell you whether or not your installer accepts input parameters through switches. Try the following from the command line `installer.exe /?` (obviously replacing installer with the name of your executable). For most command line tools, `/?` will display a help dialog for a command or executable. That may give you information as to what parameters the installer accepts.

Comment: What are you installing?

Comment: Ah, interesting. My two .exe's are the Arduino IDE, and a version of Java. I also have two .MSI's but I think those better lend themselves to cmd line installations.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide any insight into how those installers work, and you will have to investigate whether or not they are command line compatible.